# Is it possible to integrate real numbers into my custom vocabulary within the framework of model theory?

Tags: first-order-logic, real-numbers, model-theory, mathematical-modeling

So, I want to use model theory to approach an applied task. Developing the corresponding vocabulary, I realized I needed real numbers within my formulas and, thus, real numbers within the language. I decided to introduce a sort of Real Number, function, and relation symbols representing the standard arithmetic operations, order relations, etc. As I understand, I cannot just say that the interpretation of this sort is one particular constant set for all structures. Another approach would be to specify all axioms of real numbers so that the sort implementations are mutually isomorphic within all structures. I could say that I assume those axioms exist within the theory without defining them explicitly. However, I'm not sure it is possible.

So, my questions are:

1. It may be better just to abandon the idea of approaching an applied task using model theory, which seems to fit better for dealing with abstract structures. What do you think?
2. If it's generally okay to approach the modelling of a real-world system using model theory, how can I use real numbers within my vocabulary?

Edit:
I can formulate the question concisely. How do you use real numbers in your vocabulary (language) and consequently within formulas in model theory?

Edit:
As Z. A. K. suggested in the comments, the question may look like this:

"If my language $L$ includes a sort $R$, binary operations $+$, $\cdot$ on $R$, and binary relations $<$, $\leq$ on $R$, what is the preferred/standard/customary way of stating/enforcing/requiring that the $\textit{interpretation}$ of the sort $R$ in any $L$-structure I consider should be $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual arithmetic and ordering?"

Comment: This seems way too vague and way too unclear to me.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, I should've asked how to deal with or use real numbers within a vocabulary (language) of model theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think I might have grasped the underlying question, hopefully Seeker will clarify. I believe the intended question is something like the following. "If my language $L$ includes a sort $R$, binary operations $+,\cdot$ on $R$, and binary relations $<,\leq$ on $R$, what is the preferred/standard/customary way of stating/enforcing/requiring that the interpretation of the sort $R$ in any $L$-structure I consider should be $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual arithmetic and ordering?" Where preferred means something like *the way practicing model theorists would do it*.

Comment: @Z. A. K., thank you so much. That's exactly what I had in mind! One may also need the constant symbols 1 and 0. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I think you need to supply us with some more context. What kind of "applied task" are you looking at? The real numbers have been formalised in all the main interactive theorem proving systems and those formalisations have been deployed in lots of interesting applications.

Answer (score 2):

In general, **everything** gets messier. While a version of the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem persists (e.g. if our "target structure" is $\mathbb{R}$ we just replace $\aleph_0$ with $2^{\aleph_0}$), the compactness theorem - which is far more crucial in most applications - breaks horribly. Indeed, deep set-theoretic issues enter even seemingly-basic questions; see e.g. [this old MO question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394526/is-this-compactness-property-for-satisfiability-on-mathbbr-consistent) and its periphera.

A useful phrase here is "classification theory over a predicate" - see e.g. the introduction to [Pillay/Shelah's paper of that name](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-26/issue-4/Classification-theory-over-a-predicate-I/10.1305/ndjfl/1093870929.full). So the topic is indeed studied. But I would be very hesitant to expect the usual tools from first-order model theory to apply directly to any interesting problem in this setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry if I ask a dumb question, but from what I understand, dealing with real numbers is not feasible. What could be an alternative to model theory? I want to be able to define some axioms and then do some verification and validation. For the domain-specific things, first-order logic seems to be sufficient. I don't want anything complicated involving real numbers. For example, I would like to have a real-valued function defined on a sort and compare the value of the result of applying the function to two elements of that sort.

Comment: @Seeker Why not instead have a binary relation on that sort interpreted as "$f(x)\leq f(y)$", where $f$ is your real-valued function?

Comment: @Alex Kruckman, thanks for your idea. However, how would I ensure that interpretation to be true for all structures? I think the only way to do so is to impose axioms, but then I need to have a sort for the real numbers along with order relation symbols within the vocabulary.